# How to find the missing angle on this figure

Tags: geometry, circles, quadrilateral

I tutored a student today and we were both stumped on the following question:

> [image]

My thought process was that since $\angle$J is an inscribed angle, we can say that arc ILK = $222^{\circ}$ I don't think that gets me anywhere as I am not sure how to work with the lines $y - 2$ and $6$. Any hints would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I know taking snapshots makes it rather difficult to track the problem if others had questions about it, but it came from my student's school portal, so I do not have direct access to its location.

Comment: Do you need to find $\angle ILK$? Do you know sum of opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral is $180^{\circ}$?

Comment: It would help out. With that being said, $\angle$x = 69${\circ}$, where arc IJK = 138{\circ}$

Comment: Yes $m(IJK)=360-222=138$.

Comment: Okay, I can definitely take it from here.

Comment: But what are you trying to find? The angle or the length?

Comment: Just the angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\;I\hat{J}K\;$ and $\;I\hat{L}K\;$ are opposite angles in a cyclic quadrilateral, their sum is $\;180^\text{o}$, hence

$I\hat{L}K=180^\text{o}-I\hat{J}K=180^\text{o}-111^\text{o}=69^\text{o}.$

Moreover

$y-2=6$

because tangent segments to a circle from the same external point $\;M\;$ are congruent.

Therefore

$y=8\;.$